# Vertical image align in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm having problems with the vertical alignment of pictures with 2 text-lines caption in Safari browsers. Whilst Chrome, Firefox and IE work flawless, Safari aligns by the second text line caption instead of by the image. Here's the problem:

Chrome, Firefox and IE working nice:
http://postimg.org/image/mvxxkkpb1/

Safari showing wrong alignment
http://postimg.org/image/5splknbcl/

Here's about img

```
.polaroid { 
    width: 185px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 34px 36px 26px 39px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0px auto 20px auto; 
    zoom: 1; 
}  

.polaroidimage { 
    width: 185px; 
    height: 170px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    display: block; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

And here about the titles (first caption line) and date (second caption line)

```
.polaroidtitle { 
    font-family: "Times New Roman"; 
    font-size: 11px; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    letter-spacing: 2px; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    width: 170px; 
    height: 45px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    line-height: 1.1em; 
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px; 
    color: #111111; 
    text-align: left;
} 
div.polaroidtitle a { 
    color: #111111; 
    text-decoration: none;   
} 
div.polaroidtitle a:hover { 
    color: #888888;  
} 
.polaroiddate { 
    font-family: "Times New Roman"; 
    font-size: 11px; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    letter-spacing: 2px; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    width: 170px; 
    height: 19px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    line-height: 1.1em; 
    padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px; 
    color: #888888; 
    text-align: left; 
}
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide html and css.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you:

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper {
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

.img-wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.img {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}


p {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/d1Lsq9jq/

Comment: Hmm... Shouldn't it be enough by adding/deleting vertical-alignment of picture/text at the style.css?

Comment: I need to see your HTML code to answer this question.